# Is there a way to repeat some tests for a week by using testNG framework?

Tags: automation, testng

I need to run a test for a week. I tried several ways.
1. Use factory to add test. All cases run after the factory method finished. So I could not judge how many tests to add.
2. Changed TestNG class, rewrite some methods. Only works when I need to repeat all tests.

Is there any good way to implement that?

Comment: What do you mean - run a test for a week?

Comment: Yes. Repeat a test for a week and end the test automatically after that. For example, I start testNG.run() at Monday, then the automation code automatically run and repeat the test again and again till the next Monday. As I don't know how much time will be needed to run them for 1 time. I could not decide how many times will be needed for a week. So I need a way that testNG could count the time for me, and end it when the time end.

Comment: Also, I need to have 1 consolidated report. So will not have more than 1 testNG object.

Comment: For my second trail, it doesn't work as I want to run testA, testB, testC for the first time. Then in later times, I need to run testB, testC only, and repeat them for a week. My solution repeats all tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a thought of change both XmlSuite and testNG class. Add isRepeat and time2Repeat properites for XMLSuite and change testNG method runSuitesSequentially to support repeat running. Will have a try later.

The solution might work, but feels like a hack. If anyone could provide more decent way, please provide your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: Though it's not a decent way, it works anyway and works fine during the past few months testing in my case.